# Eclipse RCP File Browser in ViewPart or Editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, filesystems, eclipse-rcp

I am implementing a file browser, in Eclipse RCP, using a TreeViewer.  Would it be best to put it in an Editor or ViewPart.  I ask because, I need to be able to pass the root path for the browser and do not know of a way to do so with a view.  As views are not instantiated directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Eclipse FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_the_difference_between_a_view_and_an_editor%3F), regarding the differences between Editors and Views:

> - There is generally only one instance of a given view per workbench page, but there can be several instances of the same type of editor.
> - Editors can appear in only one region of the page, whereas views can be moved to any part of the page and minimized as fast views.
> - Editors can be in a dirty state, meaning that their contents are unsaved and will be lost if the editor is closed without saving.
> - Views have a local toolbar, whereas editors contribute buttons to the global toolbar.
> - Editors can be associated with a file name or an extension, and this association can be changed by users.

Your file browser could really use a View instead of an Editor here.

You can get all the instantiated Views through:

```
 PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getViewRegistry().getViews();
```

and then get it [from its view id](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=322074&).

Comment: Thank you very much, VonC.  That answers my question.